# UV4L webrtc broker server on public ip

Tags: pi-3, server, uv4l

## Current Situation

I'm using two-way webrtc streaming service on UV4L.

As a default, UV4L server is deployed on raspberry pi.

We can connect to UV4L's websocket server through **raspberry pi's local ip** such as wss://**192.168.0.100:8080**/stream/webrtc.

[image]

## Expectation & Purpose

But I need to make UV4L server deploy on outside server with public ip such as ec2. I want to use that ec2 server as a broker.

So wherever a user is, he can connect to RPI's WebRTC streaming server.
I think this can be an alternative of port forwarding.

[image]

## Qustion

Is this idea possible? And how can I implement it?

ps.
I set an ec2's ip on server option '--bind-host-address=13.125.xxx.xxx',
but it doesn't work. I think additional handling on server side is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `UV4L` is not a `WebRTC SFU` itself, I do not think that makes sense. To do what you want you will have to deploy the [Janus Gateway SFU](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/) on your public EC2  instance. UV4L supports Janus videorooms. In other words the pipeline will become: Rpi (UV4L) <--> Janus Gateway SFU on EC2 (Videoroom) <--> WebBrowsers.

Comment: Does Janus Gateway SFU video room supports two way audio/video streaming?